# How to set Spring datasource url environment property in AWS Beanstalk, if it contains forbidden characters?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm migrating a Spring Boot application from Azure to AWS Beanstalk. The Spring Boot application needs a `spring.datasource.url` connection string for database connection. The whole connection string is currently set in Azure and can be accessed as an environment property. The connection string looks like this `jdbc:sqlserver://xyz.database.windows.net:1433;database=developdb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;`

How can I achieve the same in AWS Beanstalk, when the connection string contains forbidden chars like semicolon, which is AFAIK not supported by Beanstalk configuration? I don't want the connection string to be neither part of source code nor build result.

Comment: What do you mean that its not supported? What's wrong by passing them as [env variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console)?

Comment: Environment property limits: Values can contain any alphanumeric characters, white space, and the following symbols: _ . : / = + \ - @ ' "

No semicolon allowed in value.

Comment: The are many ways to overcome this. Such as pass individual components, use different character than ';' and the replace it in your code, use SSM Parameter store.

Comment: If it was my property, I could store it encoded using safe chars only. And then decode in in my code before use. This is however Spring's property.

Comment: How does [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) work? AWS provides details on how to deploy spring boot on EB and they pass db details as individual env variables, like I suggested. This will not work in your case?

Comment: _they pass db details as individual env variables_ - no, they don't. Only username/password are separate. Once again, see my connection string: `jdbc:sqlserver://xyz.database.windows.net:1433;database=developdb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;`